# Moveit2 is not available in ROS2 Foxy on Windows

Tags: windows, ros2, moveit

There was a mention on https://moveit.ros.org/install-moveit2/binary-windows/ that Foxy on Windows has Moveit2 in it, so I installed it, but I wasn't able to use Moveit.

If anyone knows how to use moveit2 with Ros2 on Windows, I would like to know how to do it.

Comment: https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/Moveit/moveit_tutorials.html

Comment: I solved the problem with reference to that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/GettingStarted/SetupRos2.html

It was in ros-foxy-desktop installed from here.